# d3 locale time format

Tags: d3.js, locale, time-format

I want to change my months and days language to my language with d3 time format v6. I use some method

method 1:

```
const localeTime = {
    "days": ["Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jumat", "Sabtu"],
    "months": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", "Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember"]
  };
  
  const localeFormat = d3.locale(localeTime);
  
  const formatTime = localeFormat.timeFormat("%d %B %Y");
  
  console.log(formatTime(date));
```

I get `d3.locale is not a function` error. Then I change to `d3.timeFormatLocale` and `d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale` (Method 2)

Method 2:

```
const localeTime = {
    "days": ["Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jumat", "Sabtu"],
    "months": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", "Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember"]
  };
  
  const localeFormat = d3.timeFormatLocale(localeTime);
  
  const formatTime = localeFormat.timeFormat("%d %B %Y");
  
  console.log(formatTime(date));
```

I get this error

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at wy (VM25 d3.min.js:2)
    at Object.py [as timeFormatLocale] (VM25 d3.min.js:2)
```

when I don't use the locale as the formatter, the format still won't work because of the locale definition

```
const localeTime = d3.timeFormatLocale({
    "days": ["Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jumat", "Sabtu"],
    "months": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", "Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember"]
  });
  
  const formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d %B %Y"); //I don't use the locale this time
  
  console.log(formatTime(date)); //It should be normally formatted as English date, but is not
```

and I still get the `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error. When I delete the locale definition, the formatter works fine in English

full code on https://codepen.io/louislugas/pen/OJmmzwd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **First**, you are missing some **definition** required for
   `d3.timeFormatLocale(definition)`,

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locales), the definition **must include** the following properties:

- `dateTime` - the date and time (%c) format specifier (e.g., "%a %b %e %X %Y").
- `date` - the date (%x) format specifier (e.g., "%m/%d/%Y").
- `time` - the time (%X) format specifier (e.g., "%H:%M:%S").
- `periods` - the A.M. and P.M. equivalents (e.g., ["AM", "PM"]).
- `days` - the full names of the weekdays, starting with Sunday.
- `shortDays` - the abbreviated names of the weekdays, starting with Sunday.
- `months` - the full names of the months (starting with January).
- `shortMonths` - the abbreviated names of the months (starting with January).

2. **Secondly**, it's better to use custom name to prevent it using predefined names/variables.

Let me know if the following code works for you:

You can simply modify the properties inside

```
var ID_Time = {
        "dateTime": "%d %B %Y",
        "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
        "time": "%H:%M:%S",
        "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
        "days": ["Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jumat", "Sabtu"],
        "shortDays": ["Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jumat", "Sabtu"],
        "months": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", "Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember"],
        "shortMonths": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", "Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember"]
  };
  
var IDTime = d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(ID_Time);
  
var customformatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d %B %Y");
  
console.log(customformatTime(maxDate));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not reading it thoroughly

Comment: @louislugas Did it solve your problem? Your Welcome! Glad if it helped.

Comment: yes I did, I didn't read the "must include" part